# Is it possible to have a "global" queue when using TeamBuild?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

When I queue two builds from the same Team Project, the first one starts immediately and the second is queued to run after the first is complete.  However, when queuing two builds from different projects, they both start immediately.  Is it possible to use this "queue" feature for builds from more than one project?  I would like every build to be queued until the build server is idle.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the queuing is for a build agent, and doesnt have anything to do with the project? (Or at least thats what your question makes me think)

Comment: Quite so.  Another way of asking the question is "how can I share build agents across projects?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  At the moment (TFS2008) build agents are tied to Team Projects.  You can obviously have the same build server defined as a build agent on multiple team projects, but like you have noticed the queuing functionality doesn't work how you want when you share build servers like this.